# Google App Engine Standard environment .NET 6

Tags: google-app-engine, .net-6.0

While .NET6 already be supported by AWS (Lamda) Function and Azure Function.
Do anyone know is GAE will able to support .NET6 in standard environment.
(I know GAE already supported in flexible environment, but it's not matching my requirements while server should able scale from 0, not 1)

Comment: What about Cloud Run? It's Serverless too, supports custom runtimes (so should support .NET) and will scale from 0 and not 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the moment, **.NET** is only supported on App Engine Flex based on this documentation on [app engine environments](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#app-engine-environments).

> The flexible environment is optimal for applications with the following characteristics:
>
> - Source code that is written in a version of any of the supported programming languages:
>   **Python**, **Java**, **Node.js**, **Go**, **Ruby**, **PHP**, or **.NET**.

As per @NoCommanLine's comment, yes you can deploy your **.NET** service on Cloud Run. Based on the documentation on [Cloud Run minimum instances (services)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances):

> By default, container instances have `min-instances` turned off, with a setting of `0`. You can change this default using the Google Cloud console, the gcloud command line, or a YAML file when you [create a new service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#service) or [deploy a new revision](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#revision).

You can follow this link on how to [deploy a .NET service to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-dotnet-service).

If you really want **.NET** to be available on Google App Engine Standard, you may file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). This won't be a guarantee that the feature would be available soon but it would be worth a shot.